# windows phone 8.1 ListView sticky header

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

SOF Tribe,

I'm trying to understand and implement the listview sticky header concept in a Windows Phone 8.1 app. It's a common enough behavior but for the life of me I can't find an example that implements it in a simple fashion with the interaction I require.

The top band of a ListViewItem (which I'm assuming is the header) must stick to the top of the list view while the body of the ListViewItem scrolls up underneath it. Until the next ListViewItem header butts up to the first header and "pushes" it up.

https://db.tt/BvZgm3Bn

(I'm not allowed yet to post an image into this space...)

Please excuse the crude mockup.

This seems like a easy kill but, well, there it is.

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WP8.0 with `LongListSelector` it was done with grouping with `IsGroupingEnabled=true`.

In WP8.1 with `ListView` and `GridView` it is done with grouping of your dataset into a `CollectionViewSource` but this time you also need to define a `GroupStyle`.  Your dataset is then bind to a `CollectionViewSource` which has `IsSourceGrouped` set to true in place of `IsGroupingEnabled`.

If you need help grouping your dataset (from a flat list) think it as a `List<List<dataitem>>` where the outter list also has a key value.  Search SO / Google on how to do this if you're new to grouping.

---

Full examples can be found here:

[MSDN: How to group items in a list or grid (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh780627.aspx)

Comment: Researching now. Thanks for the pointers.

What a nightmare. With Microsoft it's always three steps forward, two steps back. I'll have to leave this treatment on a backburner for now. It seems such a simple behavior and is just done on iOS and Android. But for Windows, ugh!

Comment: @ManniMarquesa Everything is doubly hard compare to other systems.  But if you're used to WPF and MVVM it should be relatively easy.  But I agree that it should be easier for someone coming from another ecosystem.